# Angular Bootstrap alerts do not dismiss on a timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, alerts

I am trying to add alerts from Angular Bootstrap and on timeout dismiss itself. However it does not dismiss itself. Here is the code:

```
angular.module('ui.services').service('AlertService', [
  function () {
    var alerts = [];
    this.add = function(type, msg){
        var self = this;            
        return alerts.push({
            type: type,
            msg: msg,
            close: function() {
                return self.closeAlert(this);
            }
        });
        $timeout(function(){ 
            self.closeAlert(this); 
        }, 3000);

    },
    this.closeAlert = function(alert) {
        return this.closeAlertIdx(alerts.indexOf(alert));
    },
    this.closeAlertIdx = function(index) {
        return alerts.splice(index, 1);
    },
    this.alertData = function() {
        return alerts;
    }
}]);
```

I have set the timeout but not sure what is wrong.

Comment: So in ControllerA  $scope.alerts = AlertService.alertData(); and in Controller B I am adding the alert to display as AlertService.add('success', "this is deleted", true);. So I am tieing the $scope .alerts to the local alerts array defined in alert service

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/alert/alert.js#L22-L31

`<alert dismiss-on-timeout='2000'>...</alert>`

Answer (score 1):

Your `$timeout` is never called because you return just before.

Otherwise, at a glance, everything seems to be correct.

Comment: so not sure how i could run teh timeout before i do a return here

Comment: what do you mean? by placing it _before_ the return

Comment: yes, i get that but in this case the alert does not even show up as the alert is not triggered, as the $scope property which is used between two controllers is initialized later with the alerts array from teh alert service call

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... What $scope property? You may need to show more code or create a new question.

Comment: So in ControllerA  I have $scope.alerts = AlertService.alertData(); and in Controller B I am adding the alert to display as AlertService.add('success', "this is deleted", true);. So I am tieing the $scope .alerts to the local alerts array defined in alert service –

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Comments are for clarifying answers - in this case you either ran into another problem that is not easy to convey via comments or do not have enough information/code in your original question. Please either open a new question or amend this question to give a broader context.